# Scipy least squares positional argument issue

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I am trying to do a robust non-linear fitting of the following data:

r_fast:

```
[0.2065 0.2661 0.2026 0.22   0.2065 0.2661 0.264  0.2173 0.2615 0.2682
 0.407  0.4085 0.409  0.4045 0.405  0.3985 0.5235 0.5846 0.5171 0.5385
 0.6415 0.7661 0.699  0.6523 0.7745 0.7332 0.842  0.9085 0.909  0.8445
 0.84   0.8635]
```

a_fast:

```
[-43.3  -3.  -86.8 -10.5 -56.2  -2.5  -7.2 -12.2  -4.6  -9.  -21.3  -2.
  -3.2  -2.7  -5.8  -6.8 -15.5  -1.8 -22.1  -0.5  -8.7  -0.8   0.   -3.3
  -0.8  -0.8 -12.5  -0.5  -0.7   0.3  -1.   -1.2]
```

I tried the following approach. However, I am receiving an error on this line:

```
res_soft_l1 = least_squares(f, x, loss='soft_l1', f_scale=0.1, args=(r_fast, a_fast))
```

The error is:

```
f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x2'
```

All code as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
def f(r_fast, x0, x1, x2):
    return x[0] + r_fast**x[1] * x[2]
data= pd.read_table('/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/Data.txt', dtype=float, header=None, sep='\s+').values
r_fast=data[:,1]
a_fast=data[:,2]
r_min=np.min(r_fast)
r_max=np.max(r_fast)
x = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 0.0])
rr= np.linspace(r_min, r_max, len(r_fast))
res_soft_l1 = least_squares(f, x, loss='soft_l1', f_scale=0.1, args=(r_fast, a_fast))
aa= f(rr, *res_soft_l1.x)
plt.xlabel('r_fast', fontsize=30)
plt.ylabel('a_fast', fontsize=30)
plt.scatter(r_fast, a_fast, c='burlywood', s=10**2)
plt.plot(rr, aa, linewidth=3, label='Power law fit')
plt.legend(fontsize=25, loc=8, framealpha=1.0, edgecolor='maroon') 
plt.show()
```

I am unable to figure out what I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues with the code .

1. The function must return the "residuals", that is the error between the prediction and actual values (y) and not the prediction. I guess `a_fast` are the actual values in your case.
2. The parameters to be optimized must always be the first argument to the function. In this case [x0, x1,and x2]
3. Any other additional parameters of the function should be passed as `args`to the `least_squares` function. I believe "r_fast" is your additional parameter.

Following code is the minimal code that  works.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

r_fast = np.array([0.2065 ,0.2661,0.2026,0.22,0.2065,0.2661,0.264,0.2173,0.2615,0.2682
,0.407,0.4085,0.409,0.4045,0.405,0.3985,0.5235,0.5846,0.5171,0.5385
,0.6415,0.7661,0.699,0.6523,0.7745,0.7332,0.842,0.9085,0.909,0.8445
,0.84,0.8635])
a_fast = np.array([-43.3 , -3. , -86.8 ,-10.5 ,-56.2,  -2.5 , -7.2 ,-12.2,  -4.6  ,-9., -21.3  ,-2  , -3.2,  -2.7 , -5.8 , -6.8 ,-15.5 , -1.8, -22.1 , -0.5 , -8.7,  -0.8,   0. ,  -3.3 ,  -0.8,  -0.8, -12.5,  -0.5,  -0.7,   0.3 , -1. ,  -1.2])

def f(X ,r_fast):
    x0 ,x1 ,x2 = X
    return x0 + r_fast**x1 * x2 -a_fast



x_init = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 0.0])

res_soft_l1 = least_squares(f, x_init, args= ([r_fast]) ,loss='soft_l1', f_scale=0.1)
```

output:

```
res_soft_l1.x

array([-5.43168803e+03,  1.31665146e-03,  5.43206946e+03])
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. However, I am geting a small R_Sq value. My belief was this approach will provide a higher R_Sq. Any suggestion on how to optimize the R_Sq?

Comment: Preprocessing the data (removing the outliers )  , providing better initial guess  may help  .

Answer (score 1):

This is because `x` need 4 arguments but is only receiving 3.
In the line `least_squares(f, x, loss='soft_l1', f_scale=0.1, args=(r_fast, a_fast))`, `least_squares` calls `f` with the following arguments:

```
f(r_fast=x, x0=r_fast, x1=a_fast, x2=)
```

As you can see `x2` is missing. In any case none of these would help because your function `f` doesn't use `x0`, `x1` or `x2`.

You can change your function definition to:

```
def f(x, r_fast):
    return x[0] + r_fast**x[1] * x[2]
```

and `least_squares` call to

```
least_squares(f, x, loss='soft_l1', f_scale=0.1, args=(r_fast))
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried following your suggestion. However, receiving this error: f() takes 2 positional arguments but 33 were given